# How to get number or columns of a row from table with group by less columns?

Tags: oracle10g

Hi this one is my Table

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
|  name    |   sal    |  dept   |  age   | subdpt |
+----------+----------+---------+--------+--------+
|  sourav  |   1000   |  4      |  20    |  10    |
|  ravi    |   1333   |  4      |  21    |  20    |
|  dinesh  |   1444   |  5      |  22    |  30    |
|  kumar   |   1000   |  5      |  23    |  30    |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

I want all columns with max sal group by dept and subdpt.
please guide me.

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  Stack Overflow is not a free homework service.

Comment: yes I tried lot

Comment: But did not get any solution.

Comment: `yes I tried lot` then just add one of those attempts into your question, PLEASE read the HELP on how to ask a question. https://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `MAX(sal) OVER()` the details below

Look at this result first:

```
    select *
    , max(sal) over() max_sal
    from yourtable
```

Then apply the wanted filtering to that data:

```
select * from (
    select *
    , max(sal) over() max_sal
    from yourtable
    ) d
where sal = max_sal
```